# Why parallel/concurrent access to graphAPI to speed up retrieval of data (say "likes") fails sometimes

Tags: facebook-graph-api, concurrency, facebook-apps

We have tried to speed up our app by getting the initial information on a user of our app through a set of parallel calls using several ironworkers (dev.iron.io) on a ruby on rails based system. 
we have all the tokens needed. 
When it comes to retrieving "likes" - it fails. Initially it failed ones in a while, now it fails all the time. So we end up with an empty-set for likes which crushes our app.

Any thoughts/ideas/solutions to why this may be occurring?

Can it be that the graphAPI has some problem with concurrent access to the same fbID?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Did you find any answer?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you exceeded Facebook limits. You can not send as much API requests as you want. Facebook can sometimes respond with errors User request limit reached or Application request limit reached. It is called throttling or [API rate limiting](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/api-rate-limiting/). Correct response of your app should be to reduce the number of queries. Google has something similar and his preffered solution is to [reduce queries exponentially](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreErrors?hl=en#backoff). This techniques is well known in networking as [Exponential Backoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff).